# Show isomorphism $W_1 \hookrightarrow V \twoheadrightarrow W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $\langle , \rangle$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form with the signature $(p,q)$ on a real vectorspace $V$ and $W_1, W_2$ subspaces, such that the restriction $\langle , \rangle |_{W_i}$ is non-degenerate with signature $(p,0)$.

Show that for the orthogonal direct sum decomposition $V = W_2 \oplus W_2^\perp$ and the induced projection $V \to W_2$ the composition $$W_1 \hookrightarrow V \twoheadrightarrow W_2$$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: From the data you have, what do you know about the dimensions of $W_1,W_2$ and $V$?

Comment: Well, to be an isomorphism the dimensions of $W_1$ and $W_2$ have to be equal, and since $V$ is the direct sum of $W_2 \oplus W_2$ it should have the same dimension as $W_1$ and $W_2$. To be honest I'm confused of the data, I don't see how it all connects...

Comment: Point 1: What does the signature of the bilinear form signify? Point 2: What does it mean that the form is nondegenerate (on $V$, resp. on $W_i$)?

Comment: The signature gives the rank and dimension of the bilinear form with $p+q$ and being non-degenerate means that the determinant of the gramian matrix is non zero and that the map $V \to V^*,v \mapsto \langle v,\cdot \rangle$ is injective.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That's right, but only in part what I was aiming for (but, how were you to know what I was aiming for). Anyway, since the form is non-degenerate on both $W_i$ and has the same signature on both, it follows that $\dim W_1 = \dim W_2$. Now, for $W_1 \hookrightarrow V \twoheadrightarrow W_2$ to be an isomorphism, what still is needed is that $W_1 \cap W_2^\perp = \{0\}$. That follows from the signatures. But to see that, you need to know what the signature means, what the parts stand for.

Comment: did you mean $W_2 \cap W_2^\perp = {0}$? This would be equivalent to the non-degenerate assumption then. I dont know, how it could be a consequence from the signatures...

Comment: No, I meant $W_1 \cap W_2^\perp = \{0\}$. We want to show that the composition of the inclusion of $W_1$ into $V$ with the projection of $V$ onto $W_2$ with kernel $W_2^\perp$ is an isomorphism. For that, we must have that it is injective (by dimensions, that is also sufficient), and the injectivity of the composition is exactly that the image of the inclusion has trivial intersection with the kernel of the projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature $(p,q)$ of the bilinear form gives the maximal dimensions of the subspaces on which $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is positive respectively negative definite.

Hence the premise that the restriction of the bilinear form to both $W_i$ is nondegenerate with signature $(p,0)$ means

- $\dim W_1 = \dim W_2 = p$,
- $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\lvert_{W_i}$ is positive definite, and
- $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is not positive definite on any subspace properly containing one of the $W_i$.

Now, with the injection $\iota \colon W_1 \hookrightarrow V$ and the projection $\pi \colon V \twoheadrightarrow W_2$ with kernel $W_2^\perp$, since the dimensions of $W_1$ and $W_2$ are the same, the composition $\pi \circ \iota$ is an isomorphism if and only if it is injective. We have

$$\ker (\pi\circ \iota) = \iota^{-1}(\ker \pi) = W_1\cap \ker\pi = W_1 \cap W_2^\perp,$$

so we must prove that $W_1\cap W_2^\perp = \{0\}$.

Consider the subspace $U = W_2 \oplus (W_1 \cap W_2^\perp)$ of $V$. Deduce that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\lvert_U$ is positive definite, and hence $\pi\circ\iota$ is an isomorphism.